# What are the correct answers to The Frog's questions, and what is the reward when I get them all correct?

Tags: candy-box

I recently encountered The Frog in the Swampy Swamp:

[image: Hello. I'm The Frog. I can provide you candies, and lots of things. I know how much you love candies. But I feel alone in this swamp. I'd like to play with you before. If you answer my questions correctly, the sweetest sweets will be yours.]
<sup>"Hello. I'm The Frog. I can provide you candies, and lots of things. I know how much you love candies. But I feel  alone in this swamp. I'd like to play with you before. If you answer my questions correctly, the sweetest sweets will be yours."</sup>
**What are the correct answers to The Frog's questions, and what is the reward when I get them all correct?** (Also, what if I get them wrong?)

Comment: You can answer the Frog's questions indefinitely. There is no penalty for a wrong answer. The rewards are a bunch of candy, and eventually, a Chocolate Bar. As for the answers, I'd need to look up the questions again.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The frog has 6 questions. You can answer as many times wrong as you want.

Capitalisation and whitespace don't matter on the answer, `y E   s` is exactly the same as `yes`.

#### Question 1

```
First question : do you _really_ love candies?
```

*Correct answer*

```
yes
```

*reward*

```
10 candies
```

#### Question 2

```
Second question : if A implies B and B implies C, 
and D implies A, and E implies D, what does A imply?
```

*Correct answers*

```
c
b
b and c
c and b
```

*reward*

```
100 candies
```

#### Question 3

```
Third question. Consider 10 days. 
If I give you 1 candy on the first day, 
and each other day I give you twice more candies than the previous one, 
how much candies will I give you on the day number 10?
```

*Correct answer*

```
512
```

*reward*

```
512 candies
```

#### Question 4

```
Fourth question : if you could be whatever you want, what would you be?
```

*Correct answers*

```
frog
a frog
the frog
```

*reward*

```
1000 candies
```

#### Question 5

```
Here's a story : there's a fox, a lion and a wolf inside a lunar crater. 
The fox is about to bite the lion, which is about to bite the wolf, 
which is about to bite the fox. It's snowing and a shrub is watching the scene. 
Who's enjoying the story?
```

*Correct answer*

```
me
```

*reward*

```
1 chocolate bar
```

#### Question 6

```
Now, just type the answer to that question and 
I'll give you a very special present : 
what is the only thing to go beyond the limits of our universe ?
```

*Correct answers*

```
the answer to that question
the answer
answer
answer to that question
```

*reward*

```
5 berserk potions
```

Answer (score 6):

1. **yes**
2. **c** or **b**
3. **512**
4. **frog**
5. **me**
6. **the answer**