# What are all the correct answers to the Squirrel's questions, and what is the reward when I get them all correct?

Tags: candy-box-2

I encountered The Squirrel at "A tree."

```
            |   |                                                            
            |   |                     "   Hello, I'm The                     
  |             |                        Squirrel. I can                     
  |             |                      provide you candies,                  
  |             |                      and lots of things.                   
                |                      I know how much you                   
                |        _.-'''-,      love candies. But I                   
                |      .'        `\     feel alone in this                   
                |     /           /          forest.       "                 
       |        |    /      .--^_^                                           
       |        |    |     /  C ,,\                                          
                |    |    |   \  _.)                           ___           
                |     \   |   /  \                   ____.----'.-'           
                |      '-, \./ \)\)               .-' --  __.-'              
    |            \        `-/   );/           ___/  - _.-'                   
    |             \_________''--'-'________.-' --    /                       
    |              -   --        -  -     -     __.-'                        
                     -    --    -     --   --  /                             
                   _________________________.-'
```

He asks you some questions. **What are the correct answers, and what is the reward for getting them correct?**

Comment: (I asked and self-answered this to keep all of the answers to the questions in one place, like [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116133/) from Candy Box 1. (we already have questions for specific ones, like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137037/), [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137051/), and [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137041/).))

Comment: Since this caused the original versions of the questions to be closed as dupes, which I don't feel very comfortable with, I raised a [meta question about it here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7901/3062)

Comment: I'm not sure why this post was reopened, since we decided on meta it should be closed.

Comment: To be fair, we didn't clearly decide that on meta. We just decided that the others shouldn't have been closed as dupes. My answer didn't really have a suggestion for what to do with this question, since I have no idea. That's also why I've refrained from voting on it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> First one : do you really love candies? (answer in english)

Correct answer: "yes" (just like in Candy Box 1)
<sup>alternatives: "y", "yeah", "yeap", "yep"</sup>
Reward: 20 candies

> Now complete this sequence of letters and you'll get a new reward : S, E, I, D, N, A, ?

Correct answer: "C" (it's CANDIES spelled backwards)
<sup>alternatives: "letter c", "the letter c"</sup>
Reward: 100 candies

> Next question : how many candies does the candiest person in the world possess?

Correct answer: [however many candies you have currently]
Reward: 500 candies

> In an ancient forest grows a very old tree, on which live the most intelligent animals in this world. It is said that this tree has 60 roots, 360 branches and 2160 leaves. How many marks can you find on its trunk?

Correct answer: "10" (the squirrel is talking about the tree that he is on)
<sup>alternatives: "ten", "10 marks", "ten marks"</sup>
Reward: 3 lollipops

> Under a full moon, I throw a yellow hat into the red sea. What happens to the yellow hat?

Correct answer: "it gets wet," or "it floats"
<sup>alternatives: "wet", "it becomes wet", "it become wet", "becomes wet", "become wet", "it get wet", "its wet", "it got wet", "it is wet", "it is wet now", "its wet now", "float", "floats", "its floating", "it is floating", "floating", "it float"</sup>
Reward: 3 chololate bars

> The game is Tic-Tac-Toe. We play on a 3 by 3 game board. You will use the X sign while I will use the O sign. We place our signs alternatively, and the goal is to get three signs in a row. I'll let you go first!

Correct answer (solution): first go in the middle square, then any corner, then get three in a row by going outside of the grid

```
      _____________________
     |      |      |  __  |                                       
     |      |      | |  | |                                       
     |      |      | |__| |                                       
     |______|______|______|                                       
     |      |      |      |                                       
     |      |  \/  |      |                                       
     |      |  /\  |      |                                       
     |______|______|______|                                       
     |      |      |  __  |                                       
     |  \/  |      | |  | |                                       
     |  /\  |      | |__| |                                       
     |______|______|______|                                       

 \/                                                               
 /\
```

Reward: a key to open one of the locked houses in the village

Comment: You can just place all 3 outside of the grid if you want.

Comment: "floats" is a correct answer to the hat question too.

Comment: simply "wet" works for the hat question too.

Comment: Any similar solution involving any of the four corners on the tic-tac-toe seems to work. I did upper left corner.

Comment: @Arperum, 3ventic, Yamikuronue: Updated answer

Comment: If you really want every possible correct answer to a riddle, a quick look at the JavaScript reveals them. There are quite a few alternates.

Comment: Shouldn't all of these be in spoilers?

Comment: The Tic-Tac-Toe challenge was quite arbitrary; I won fair and square, yet the Squirrel still made his move and managed to get 3 in a row after I did, and proclaimed he had won. However, cheat and he *doesn't* make his last move, and instead says you've won. Pretty weird...

Answer (score 1):

For the tic-tac-toe, think about having an extra 3 boxes at the top of the box and just click on those.
You can use any space right next to the box and it will count.

Answer (score -5):

1. no
2. c ,because they are spelled backward
3. however many candies you have
4. 10
5. wet
6. first go in the middle square, then any corner, then get three in a row by going outside of the grid

Comment: ummm... what? Most of these are just plain wrong, and the last one is copied from my answer...